# Capybara default_max_wait_time doesnt apply new timing

Tags: ruby, capybara

I am writing a script with Capybara and Ruby and I am trying to change the default_max_wait_time from 2 sec to 200 sec. I read through the documentation but it seems like it still doesn't work for me when I am uploading the file to the be site. Could you advise what I am doing wrong, please?

```
require 'kimurai'
require 'pry'
require 'capybara/config'

# $app_path = 'path_to_the_file'

class Uploader < Kimurai::Base
  @name = "new_google_play_console_app"
  @engine = :selenium_chrome
  @start_urls = ["link_to_the_web_page"]


  def parse(response, url:, data: {})
    Capybara.configure do |config|
        config.default_max_wait_time = 200
        puts config.default_max_wait_time
    end


    browser.click_button('I’m sure, opt out', wait: 100)
    browser.attach_file($app_path) do
        browser.click_button('Browse files')
    end
    sleep 200
    browser.click_on('Save')
```

The problem is the script doesn't wait for the file to be uploaded and tries to click 'Save'. And not only here - sometimes, when I click the button the website loads results. But my script doesn't wait for it and continue to execute. So, that's why I put ```sleep`` for now. But I want to avoid it

This table appears after upload process completion:

[image]

[image]

**Thomas**, here is a code and an error. After the upload is completed, I need to click ``Save``` button which is not active until you are done with uploading.

**CODE**

```
app_releases = browser.find_link(title: 'App releases')
app_releases.click
manage_btn = browser.all(:button, text: 'Manage')
manage_btn[0].click
sleep 1
create_release_btn = browser.all(:button, text: 'Create release')
create_release_btn[1].click
browser.click_button('Opt out', wait: 100)
browser.click_button('I’m sure, opt out', wait: 100)
browser.attach_file($app_path) do
   browser.click_button('Browse files')
   browser.assert_text('App download size', wait: 200)
end
# browser.assert_text('App download size', wait: 200) - tried to put it inside the upload process and outside. Didn't work.
# sleep 200
browser.click_on('Save')
```

**ERROR:**

```
WARN: Unresolved specs during Gem::Specification.reset:
      selenium-webdriver (>= 0)
WARN: Clearing out unresolved specs.
Please report a bug if this causes problems.
I, [2020-06-10 19:10:54 +0300#37958] [M: 70296153575020]  INFO -- new_google_play_console_app: Spider: started: new_google_play_console_app
D, [2020-06-10 19:10:56 +0300#37958] [M: 70296153575020] DEBUG -- new_google_play_console_app: BrowserBuilder (selenium_chrome): created browser instance
I, [2020-06-10 19:10:56 +0300#37958] [M: 70296153575020]  INFO -- new_google_play_console_app: Browser: started get request to: https://play.google.com/apps/publish/?account=5899250864637200353#AppDashboardPlace:p=net.cityhive.store.martinbrothers&appid=4975449495408659761
2020-06-10 19:10:56 WARN Selenium [DEPRECATION] :driver_path is deprecated. Use :service with an instance of Selenium::WebDriver::Service instead.
I, [2020-06-10 19:11:00 +0300#37958] [M: 70296153575020]  INFO -- new_google_play_console_app: Browser: finished get request to: https://play.google.com/apps/publish/?account=5899250864637200353#AppDashboardPlace:p=net.cityhive.store.martinbrothers&appid=4975449495408659761
I, [2020-06-10 19:11:00 +0300#37958] [M: 70296153575020]  INFO -- new_google_play_console_app: Info: visits: requests: 1, responses: 1
D, [2020-06-10 19:11:00 +0300#37958] [M: 70296153575020] DEBUG -- new_google_play_console_app: Browser: driver.current_memory: 501740
I, [2020-06-10 19:11:37 +0300#37958] [M: 70296153575020]  INFO -- new_google_play_console_app: Browser: driver selenium_chrome has been destroyed
I, [2020-06-10 19:11:37 +0300#37958] [M: 70296153575020]  INFO -- new_google_play_console_app: Spider: stopped: {:spider_name=>"new_google_play_console_app", :status=>:completed, :error=>nil, :environment=>"development", :start_time=>2020-06-10 19:10:54 +0300, :stop_time=>2020-06-10 19:11:37 +0300, :running_time=>"42s", :visits=>{:requests=>1, :responses=>1}, :items=>{:sent=>0, :processed=>0}, :events=>{:requests_errors=>{}, :drop_items_errors=>{}, :custom=>{}}}
MacBook-Air-Nikita:spiders nikita$ ruby new_google_play_console_app.rb Liquor\ Super\ Store liquorsuper
WARN: Unresolved specs during Gem::Specification.reset:
      selenium-webdriver (>= 0)
WARN: Clearing out unresolved specs.
Please report a bug if this causes problems.
I, [2020-06-11 13:37:28 +0300#38739] [M: 70329536056940]  INFO -- new_google_play_console_app: Spider: started: new_google_play_console_app
D, [2020-06-11 13:37:29 +0300#38739] [M: 70329536056940] DEBUG -- new_google_play_console_app: BrowserBuilder (selenium_chrome): created browser instance
I, [2020-06-11 13:37:29 +0300#38739] [M: 70329536056940]  INFO -- new_google_play_console_app: Browser: started get request to: https://play.google.com/apps/publish/?account=5899250864637200353#AppListPlace
2020-06-11 13:37:29 WARN Selenium [DEPRECATION] :driver_path is deprecated. Use :service with an instance of Selenium::WebDriver::Service instead.
I, [2020-06-11 13:37:36 +0300#38739] [M: 70329536056940]  INFO -- new_google_play_console_app: Browser: finished get request to: https://play.google.com/apps/publish/?account=5899250864637200353#AppListPlace
I, [2020-06-11 13:37:36 +0300#38739] [M: 70329536056940]  INFO -- new_google_play_console_app: Info: visits: requests: 1, responses: 1
D, [2020-06-11 13:37:36 +0300#38739] [M: 70329536056940] DEBUG -- new_google_play_console_app: Browser: driver.current_memory: 500852
I, [2020-06-11 13:38:10 +0300#38739] [M: 70329536056940]  INFO -- new_google_play_console_app: Browser: driver selenium_chrome has been destroyed
F, [2020-06-11 13:38:10 +0300#38739] [M: 70329536056940] FATAL -- new_google_play_console_app: Spider: stopped: {:spider_name=>"new_google_play_console_app", :status=>:failed, :error=>"#<Capybara::ElementNotFound: Unable to find link or button \"Save\">", :environment=>"development", :start_time=>2020-06-11 13:37:28 +0300, :stop_time=>2020-06-11 13:38:10 +0300, :running_time=>"42s", :visits=>{:requests=>1, :responses=>1}, :items=>{:sent=>0, :processed=>0}, :events=>{:requests_errors=>{}, :drop_items_errors=>{}, :custom=>{}}}
Traceback (most recent call last):
    13: from new_google_play_console_app.rb:196:in `<main>'
    12: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/kimurai-1.4.0/lib/kimurai/base.rb:124:in `crawl!'
    11: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/kimurai-1.4.0/lib/kimurai/base.rb:124:in `each'
    10: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/kimurai-1.4.0/lib/kimurai/base.rb:128:in `block in crawl!'
     9: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/kimurai-1.4.0/lib/kimurai/base.rb:204:in `request_to'
     8: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/kimurai-1.4.0/lib/kimurai/base.rb:204:in `public_send'
     7: from new_google_play_console_app.rb:187:in `parse'
     6: from new_google_play_console_app.rb:55:in `appReleases'
     5: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/capybara-3.32.2/lib/capybara/session.rb:759:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Session>'
     4: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/capybara-3.32.2/lib/capybara/node/actions.rb:26:in `click_link_or_button'
     3: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/capybara-3.32.2/lib/capybara/node/finders.rb:52:in `find'
     2: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/capybara-3.32.2/lib/capybara/node/finders.rb:291:in `synced_resolve'
     1: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/capybara-3.32.2/lib/capybara/node/base.rb:83:in `synchronize'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/capybara-3.32.2/lib/capybara/node/finders.rb:302:in `block in synced_resolve': Unable to find link or button "Save" (Capybara::ElementNotFound)
```

Comment: If you're using `rspec`, you need to add some other expectation to substitute for the `sleep` that you have there. Perhaps you should be waiting on some kind of spinner, upload status, anything that provides feedback that your upload is still happening.

Capybara's `default_max_wait_time` is used for when an element _doesn't_ appear on the page, and will wait up to that time limit for it to appear on the page. That doesn't help in your situation here.

Comment: I don't use ```rspec``` but I think I've got your idea and it will be useful. Thank you!

Comment: What Phil said. If the button is physically clickable, increasing wait time won't achieve anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved with `browser.has_button?('Save', wait: 200)` . There is a Save button that appears after the successful upload.

Answer (score 1):

`Capybara.default_max_wait_time` is the amount of time Capybara will wait for a matching element to appear on, or disappear from the page.  In your case, that means in your script you need to determine what change on the page indicates the file has finished uploading and wait for that

```
browser.attach_file($app_path) do
    browser.click_button('Browse files')
end

# Have this look for whatever indicates the file upload has completed
browser.assert_text('Your file has uploaded', wait: 200)

browser.click_on('Save')
```

Comment: There is no text appears that indicates the end of the upload process. But there is a table that appears only after the upload process is completed. The problem is it contains dynamic classes and ids, so I cannot use them..

Any ideas on how I can handle it?
I attached two screenshots of this table and its code for your reference

Comment: @NikitaBasharkin If the table doesn't appear until after the upload process is completed then the text in that table appears then too - use the text 'App download size'

Comment: I tried it today, used exactly this text - didn’t work out

Comment: @NikitaBasharkin then post the full exact error message you’re getting

Comment: @NikitaBasharkin Why did you add the text assertion inside the attach_file block  ???  You're hiding the one error that might be useful to explain what's going on.  Also are you sure that text isn't on the page until the file has uploaded?  This would be much easier if you just provided all the info up front rather than making us ask for it piece by piece.

Comment: First, I tried it out of attach_file box. I am sure regarding the text appearance as it shows up only after the upload process is completed. I was trying not to overwhelm the question, so tried to provide with the most relevant info

Comment: @NikitaBasharkin So does the "Save" button also not appear until after the upload finishes, because the error you show is telling you the "Save" button doesn't appear on the page.  If the save button doesn't appear on the page until after the upload finishes then you could skip the `assert_text` and just do something like `browser.click_on('Save', wait: 200)` ( or is whatever includes "Save" not actually a link or button - `<a>`, `<button>`, etc)

Comment: Solved with ```browser.has_button?('Save', wait: 200)``` . There is a ```Save``` button that appears after the successful upload. So I decided to give it a try as a trigger and it worked! Thank you!!